# Menu stays collapsed after reverting back to desktop view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My menu is collapses when i switch to mobile view, which is working properly, but when i switch back to desktop view it says collapsed, unless i reload the page. How can i fix this issue without having to reload the page?

here is my code:

```
<https://codepen.io/hato15/pen/RwwbjOB>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are trying to find element by it's class after you removed it:

```
$('.show').removeClass('show');
```

Change it to something like this:

```
$('.collapse').removeClass('show');
```